# *args and **kwargs in pylons controller decorator causing error 'unexpected keyword argument 'pylons'"

Tags: decorator, pylons

I can use the following decorator on most class methods without a problem, but when I apply it to controller action methods in a Pylons Controller class, I get the error message " got an unexpected keyword argument 'pylons'

What's different about these controller actions that this decorator approach causes this error?

```
def my_decorator(func):
  def wrapper (*args, **kwargs):
     return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```